# Changing font in prettyPhoto

Tags: fonts, prettyphoto, caption

I'm using prettyPhoto for a lightbox, and it works great, but I have a problem:

I can't figure out how to change the "caption" font at the bottom of the photo. I keep looking for this online, but I can't find it. I know it must be something about changing the prettyPhoto style sheet?

Can I write my own class in my custom css file like with other font changes? If so, how do I reference the class for my caption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while since you asked, but in case you left it unresolved or anybody else is looking for the answer, there are two rules buried in 'prettyPhoto.css' without a font-family property: 'div.pp_default .pp_description' and 'div.ppt'.

The first applies to the description beneath the image and the second applies to the title at the top.